# Filling array with multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, multidimensional-array, indexing, parallel.for

I am trying to read multidimensional arrays and get the index and values of the element if it is fitting the condition with multithreading.

I divided the multidimensional array into smaller subcubes under name jobs

If the condition fits, I save the value to the samples array, and index to the ValidCubeIndexList array.  So the "samples" and the "ValidCubeIndexList" is going to be shared and used between threads.

I am not sure if this is a correct approach or not, but with parallelism, I couldn't find a way to lock iSample locally.

```
Parallel.For(0, jobs.Count, new ParallelOptions {
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = NumOfProcessor
  },
  delegate(int i, ParallelLoopState state) {

    var job = jobs[i];

    Index3 min = job.output.MinIJK;
    Index3 max = job.output.MaxIJK;

    var bulk = job.output.ToArray();

    int x = bulk.GetLength(0);
    int y = bulk.GetLength(1);
    int z = bulk.GetLength(2);

    for (int n = 0; n < x; n++) {
      for (int m = 0; m < y; m++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < z; b++) {

          int activeIndex = Get3DIndex(min.I + n, min.J + m, min.K + b, cubeIndex.I,
            cubeIndex.J, cubeIndex.K);

          if (SelectionMaskIsActive) {
            if (invFlags[activeIndex]) {

              samples[iSample] = bulk[n, m, b];

              ValidCubeIndexList[iSample] = activeIndex;
              Interlocked.Increment(ref iSample);

            }
          } else {
            samples[iSample] = bulk[n, m, b];
            ValidCubeIndexList[iSample] = activeIndex;
            Interlocked.Increment(ref iSample);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

However the `Interlocked.Increment(ref iSample)` is not working as I expected.

How can I share and use the `iSample` parameter between threads?

Comment: `However the "Interlocked.Increment(ref iSample)" is not working as I expected.` - what does it do and what did you expect? Also; I see you make use of a lot of variables defined outside the scope of the execution loop - you should be careful with that because they share state accross the threads.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Parallel.For/ForEach is meant for data parallelism, not spawning threads. It's not meant to process a queue of jobs either. `Parallel.ForEach` works by *partitioning* the input data into as many partitions as there are cores and use one worker task per partition, ensuring there's no need to synchronize access. What you wrote seems to try to process each job in a single thread. There better options for this, eg ActionBlock or TransformBlock

Comment: Could you include in the question the definition of the `samples` and `iSample` variables?

Comment: Also having the definition of the `ValidCubeIndexList` variable might help us understand your problem.

Comment: Instead of trying to modify an array, why not use a ConcurrentQueue? Although a TransformBlock could act as both a processor *and* output buffer. A TransformBlock guarantees that the output messages will be in the same order as the input messages, which means you can tell which job each result came from

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell the usage and value of `iSample` is shared over multiple threads.

Incrementing it using `Interlocked.Increment(ref iSample);` will not cause the value to be locked locally in any way, so, if you increment, you're changing the value over all the threads which often leads to unexpected results.

If your timing is as such that you rely on this behavior I recommend to use an alternative approach or mark the variable as [volatile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile), but even then its considered bad practice, because, whilst:

> The volatile keyword indicates that a field might be modified by multiple threads that are executing at the same time.

it does not guarantee direct availability of the variable over all threads, by:

> On a multiprocessor system, a volatile read operation does not guarantee to obtain the latest value written to that memory location by any processor. Similarly, a volatile write operation does not guarantee that the value written would be immediately visible to other processors.